# Совместимость Laravel с Mysql и Php

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Есть проект на Laravel 5.0. Использовалась Mysql 5.6 и Php 5.5. 
Для улучшения скорости работы перешел на Mysql 5.7 и Php 7.0. 
Могут ли возникнуть проблемы с совместимостью?

Comment: Нет.Смело переходить.Проблемы в таких случаях происходят из за неумения пользоваться ими

Comment: Спасибо. Вроде бы пока проблем не возникло.